# Break point 'break on subtree modifications' of 'html' element can not be removed in chrome devtool

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

The break point added to **html** element cannot be removed. Tried to use 'remove all DOM breakpoints', but when page refreshed, the break point get back again.

System env: Chrome 63.0.3239.108(x64) macOS 10.13.2

Comment: Do you want to inform us about this behavior, or do you have a problem and want to ask help? It is absolutely unclear from your sentence.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I want to know how to remove the breakpoint.

Comment: Did you try to remove all breakpoints from the DOM Breakpoints Pane?

Comment: yes, I chose remove all the breakpoints from the DOM breakpoints Pane. as in the pic ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOUJA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Under the Inspector, when you right-click the specific DOM element and select `Break on...`, do you see `subtree modification` selected/checked? If so, de-select/uncheck `subtree modification`.

Comment: De-select this option does not help, after the page refresh, it'll be back again. I reinstall Chrome at last and everything goes fine.